# DB set entity install priority

Tags: extension

How can I set the entity install order?
now the new table refers to a nonexistent one because the new table has not yet been created

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for the postInstall hook? https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_postInstall/

It is written in the [example section](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_postInstall/#example):

`Another potential use is to act on settings or managed entities that are created during the installation (but not necessarily in order that you want them to be created)`